# Installing a font on a client machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, fonts

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and the built-in installation tools for a C# client application. How can I use this installer to install a font on the client machine (if it's not already there)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In VS2005 (so I assume 2008 as well), right click on the File System on Target Machine, Add Special Folder -> Fonts Folder, then place your font file there.

Answer (score 4):

For me, Timothy Carter had the answer mostly right:

"right click on the File System on Target Machine, Add Special Folder -> Fonts Folder, then place your font file there."

But that was not enough.  The Fonts didn't actually get installed as system Fonts.

To install the fonts, I had to visit the Properties for each font file and change Register=vsdrfDoNoRegister to Register=vsdrfFont.  After that the Setup file I generated would also install the font!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article.

http://www.atakala.com/Browser/Item.aspx?user_id=amos&dict_id=83

The most important call is the **AddFontResource** Win32 API call altough the described sequence of operations must be respected for you to have a working font setup in the system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534231(VS.85).aspx

> The AddFontResource function adds the
>   font resource from the specified file
>   to the system font table. The font can
>   subsequently be used for text output
>   by any application.

Comment: This doesn't install the font so it's available to the system constantly. It only loads it into the current session, so it'll be lost when the system is rebooted. For a font to be installed properly it needs to be put in the system font folder and registered in the registry, in addition to this.

Comment: you are both correct - The font file should be copied into the Fonts folder and then AddFontResource called *as well*.

Comment: I've just checked that simply adding the font to the VS project's Fonts Folder is enough and was worried that I'd have to manually make these calls. Fortunately, the VS project has a Register = vsdrfFont property, so I'm going to assume that the installer does this automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using InnoSetup to deliver my VS applications. It allows you to install fonts from your system to the client system.

I never tested in Windows 7 or Vista (probably you'll have some permission issues).

Remember that not all the fonts are freely distributable.