#  Installing font on client computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fonts

I am trying to install a font on client computer. I can see the question has already been asked here [Installing a font on a client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126594/installing-a-font-on-a-client-machine)

The issue I have is, where is "File System"?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2a99e5c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it is under View -> Editor -> File System.

I can't see it on my version of VS2010 Professional. Any ideas what I need to do (do I need to install something first)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File System` is when you create a `Setup and Deployment Project` in VS. In that types of project you can put your exe, tell project, fonts in `Fonts Folder` and then it will place your fonts in client system where fonts are installed i.e. `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder of client machine.

Your link of MSDN is under `Deployment Editor`.

Open a new `Setup and Deployment` project to check.